# Weird JSON Object parsing

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying to parse info out from Wikipedia. But I have a problem by it. I don't get errors from try catch but the string I want is null .
I actually got the whole Json but have problems by dividing them here is the JSON :

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "280636": {
                "pageid": 280636,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Gary Moore",
                "extract": "Robert William Gary Moore (4 April 1952 – 6 February 2011) was a Northern Irish musician, most widely recognised as a singer and virtuoso guitarist.\nIn a career dating back to the 1960s, Moore played with musicians including Phil Lynott and Brian Downey during his teens, leading him to memberships with the Irish bands Skid Row and Thin Lizzy, and British Band Colosseum II. Moore shared the stage with such blues and rock musicians as B.B. King, Albert King, Jack Bruce, Albert Collins, George Harrison, and Greg Lake, as well as having a successful solo career. He guested on a number of albums recorded by high-profile musicians."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code to get "extract" info :

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);   // result is the String with the whole Json                       
    String desc = object.getString("extract");  //this is going to be null

} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
}
```

Im a newbie by JSON formats please help !
Are these double JSON objects ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONObject obj1 = object.getJSONObject("query");
    JSONObject obj2 = obj1.getJSONObject("pages");
    JSONObject obj3=null;
   Iterator<String> keys= obj2.keys();
   while (keys.hasNext()) 
  {
        String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
        obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject(keyValue);
  }

    String desc = obj3.getString("extract");
```

Comment: Thanks but the Input by obj3 is changing by other searches . How can I manage that ? fx 280636 to 203442

Comment: `obj3 = obj2.getJSONObject(obj2.getNames()[0])`

Comment: But now there stands "The method getNames() is undefined for the type JSONObject" . Whats wrong ? I allready imported " import org.json.*; " But this didnt helped

Comment: Thanks but why did it not worked with the method getNames ?

Comment: There is no such method like object.getNames() in java, i checked code on IDE then i found out and then got the way to resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: [There is](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getNames(org.json.JSONObject)) getNames method in java; it is however absent in the Android JSONObject. I have picked the wrong documentation, my bad

Answer (score 1):

`object.getString("extract")` returns null because the getString method does not scan the entire json for that field (what if the "extract" field was in multiple places?). It only looks at the top level.

For example, `object.getString("batchcomplete")` is valid and would return `""` instead of null.

You need to do something like this:

```
String extract = object
    .getJSONObject("query")
    .getJSONObject("pages")
    .getJSONObject("280636")
    .getString("extract");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getJSONObject()` method to parse into the **extract** element as follow:

```
String desc = object.getJSONObject("query").
getJSONObject("pages").
getJSONObject("280636").
getString("extract")
```

**Output:**

> Robert William Gary Moore (4 April 1952 – 6 February 2011) was a
>   Northern Irish musician, most widely recognised as a singer and
>   virtuoso guitarist.\nIn a career dating back to the 1960s, Moore
>   played with musicians including Phil Lynott and Brian Downey during
>   his teens, leading him to memberships with the Irish bands Skid Row
>   and Thin Lizzy, and British Band Colosseum II. Moore shared the stage
>   with such blues and rock musicians as B.B. King, Albert King, Jack
>   Bruce, Albert Collins, George Harrison, and Greg Lake, as well as
>   having a successful solo career. He guested on a number of albums
>   recorded by high-profile musicians

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-String is nested.

```
{
    "batchcomplete":"",
    "query":{
        "pages":{
            "280636":{
                "pageid":280636,
                "ns":0,
                "title":"Gary Moore",
                "extract":"Some long text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So `object.getString("extract")` looks for direct children of that object. These children are `batchcomplete` and `query`.
You have to lookup every level.

```
String desc = object.getJSONObject("query")
    .getJSONObject("pages")
    .getJSONObject("280636")
    .getString("extract");
```